# Custom progress bar not working in only Galaxy Nexus device

Tags: android, progress-bar, custom-component

I have required to create progress  bar so I did it in onDraw method by extending ProgressBar  and this code is working in all android devices except galaxy nexus .. although it not throwing and exception but the progress drawable is not updating by mean of asynctask . This code is completely working in all devices except galaxy nexus

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setColor(textColor);

    Typeface tmTypeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
    textPaint.setTypeface(tmTypeface);
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize * mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    int x = getWidth() / 2 - bounds.centerX();
    int y = getHeight() / 2 - bounds.centerY();
    canvas.drawBitmap(thumbnailBitmap, 10, y - bitmapHeight / 2, null);
    canvas.drawText(text, 15 + thumbnailBitmap.getWidth(), y, textPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(downloadBitmap, getWidth() - bitmapWidth, y - bitmapHeight / 2, null);

}
```

The problem may be with drawable and style but it is working in all version and all devices

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem you state in your question in this code snippet, but I can see lots of problems in your code per se.

I guess you are subclassing `View`, I have no idea why you `synchronized` the `onDraw` method, there's no need to do so. By making the `onDraw` method `synchronized`, you simply block all other threads from accessing your object when `onDraw` is executing, and note that `onDraw` may be called pretty frequently, if you really need synchronization, make a **small** `synchronized` block if doing so is enough.

One more thing, it is really really **BAD** idea to create a new `Paint`, `Typeface` in every call to `onDraw`, it defeats performance. Save them as instance variables and reuse them as possible as can be, even the `Rect` object should be reused.

Let's go back to your problem, if you want to create a custom progressbar, you can simply create a progressbar style and reference in your layout definitions(in XML). Create `my_progressbar.xml` under `drawable` directory and save the following in the file, reference this style in your `ProgressBar` definition like `<ProgressBar ... android:progressDrawable="@drawable/my_progressbar"/>`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#ffcccccc" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#ff000000" />
    </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#ffff6100" />
    </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Take a look at [this](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#shape) for more info on defining shapes.